# Bash Copying the Contents of One Directory to every Directory contained within a Parent Directory

Tags: bash, copy

I'd imagine this would be a simply command, but I can't find a way to copy the contents of a directory to every subdirectory contained in a parent directory. For example, let's say I wanted to copy the path:

```
user/origin
```

to all of the following directories inside the destination "target" directory. For example...

```
user/target/1, user/target/6, user/target/2, user/target/a/10, etc.
```

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What commands do you use and what are the precise error reports?

Comment: I haven't received any errors, as I simply do not know what the command would be, I can use the cp command to do this incrementally, but the parent directory contains 1000 target directories. I'm unsure of the syntax aside from copy to achieve this in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful because you can get an infinite loop, normally exec should suffice but when you are using recursion this way it causes an infinite loop so use xargs:

```
find user/target/ -type d | xargs -I {} cp -r user/origin {}
```

Comment: I apologize if I've misunderstood, but when executed this does not return an error, and it does not succeed in copying origin into any of the directories in target. What this does is copy the directory origin itself, rather than the contents of origin.

Comment: It was purely a user problem, this works beautifully. Thanks again.